# foursquare website venue search not matching up to api search

Tags: foursquare

The answer just might be alluding me, but this bugs me

I've been doing a simple search trying to find all the outdoor picnic spots near me.  So I search for picnic in my zip code, and I get a list of results.
https://foursquare.com/search?tab=tipResults&q=picnic&lat=&lng=&near=10001

I then try to do the same search using the api (the venues/explore endpoint) to see if my app works well, and I get a completely different list of places.  The api url that I've been using is
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=10001&section=outdoors&query=picnic&radius=5000&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY

BTW, If I dont include a radius, it only returns 1 entry.

Answer (score 2):

The web address you provided: https://foursquare.com/search?tab=tipResults&q=picnic&lat=&lng=&near=10001

Is tip results around 10001.

The API call you provided: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=10001&section=outdoors&query=picnic&radius=5000&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY

Is a single explore search api call.

These two are very different, and will yield different results

Try running a tip search via the API as such (API docs at [this place](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/tips/search)):

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?near=10001&query=picnic`

([direct link for testing it](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=tips/search?near=10001&query=picnic))

Let us know if this this clears it up.